# In a Notebook, How can I set every cell to be an Initialization cell?

Tags: notebooks, initialization

At present, I do this by manually setting every cell in a notebook to be Initialization cell. There must be a better way!
When I finish work  one day and re-open the notebook the next day, I want all the cells to be evaluated.

Comment: To answer the implicit Y question, you could also use `DumpSave[]` to save all the results and `Get[]` to reload them. You can save all the definitions (of variables and functions) in a whole context ``"Global`"`` might be appropriate for some workflows. Or you could work on a project in a context you define.

Comment: Another option is to use a "Wolfram Language Package" under the File/New/ Package/Script (a .wl file). The default is to use a code cell instead of an Input cell. One downside is that your output isn't preserved after you close the file, but if you're going to re-evaluate anyway, maybe that doesn't matter to you. You can still manually create Input cells and do many things supported in a .nb, including text, Graphics, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the entire notebook converted to Initialization cells, Ctrl-A the notebook, selecting all the cells and then Ctrl-8 to convert them all to Initialization cells.